# vector of vectors of all combinations of -1, +1

Tags: c++, vector, combinatorics

For any given `n`, I need to create a vector of vectors of length `n` `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, containing *all* possible combinations of `-1` and `+1`. For example, for `n=3` I need

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v = {
  { 1,  1,  1},
  { 1,  1, -1},
  { 1, -1,  1},
  { 1, -1, -1},
  {-1,  1,  1},
  {-1,  1, -1},
  {-1, -1,  1},
  {-1, -1, -1}
};
```

Any hints?

Comment: Have you tried using loops?

Comment: There are the binary representations of number from `0` to `1u << n`

Comment: Thanks. If this can be converted to `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, that'd probably be it.

Comment: General easy approach: write a recursive algorithm (calling itself with branching on +1,-1 and adding selection to local list; every end-state adding to some outer list). Then build an array from the outer list of lists. (This can be parameterized quite nicely, e.g. using +1,-1,0; if you are generating huge matrices, a loop-based approach is better because of the stack: in this case look for some combinatoric libraries as it will get more messy)

Comment: Hint: if you have a vector of ±1, try to come up with a way to obtain the *next* such vector (with respect to some natural ordering).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Following @sascha's suggestion, here's a method that appends +-1 to a given set of lists.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::vector<int>>
append_plus_minus(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> & in)
{
  auto out = in;
  out.insert(out.end(), in.begin(), in.end());
  for (std::size_t i=0; i < in.size(); i++) {
    out[i].push_back(+1);
    out[i+in.size()].push_back(-1);
  }
  return out;
}

int main() {
  const int n = 5;

  std::vector<std::vector<int>> b_combinations = {{}};
  for (std::size_t i=0; i < n; i++) {
    b_combinations = append_plus_minus(b_combinations);
  }

  for (std::size_t i=0; i < b_combinations.size(); i++) {
     for (std::size_t j=0; j < b_combinations[i].size(); j++) {
       std::cout << b_combinations[i][j] << " ";
     }
     std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this won't end up as an infinite loop? Out is always In^2 Size, which will always stay ahead of the value of `i` in the outer loop?

Comment: No idea what you mean.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Sorry accidentally pressed enter too soon. Edited comment. In addition won't this output {{1,1}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, -1} ... }? `out[2*i]` All vectors at even indices get +1. `out[2*i+1]` All vectors at odd indices get -1?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile... What is `b`? (as in `b.size()`)

Comment: @Polikdir b => b_combinations

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using the binary representation, and testing the bit value. I used [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) although you can also use the simple C-Style bit manipulations.

```
#include <bitset>

int main(){
    int n=3;
    int to = pow(2,n);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> result;
    for (int i=0; i < to; i++){
        std::bitset<32> b(i);
        std::vector<int> vec1;
        for (int j=0; j < n; j++){
            int value = b.test(j) ? 1 : -1;
            vec1.push_back(value);
        }
        result.push_back(vec1);
    }

    // Printing out result
    for (auto& vec : result){
        for (auto val : vec){
            cout << val;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

[Test Example](http://ideone.com/wK0tFS)

Answer (score 1):

For larger values of `(n)`, you might want to improve the efficiency:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
v.reserve(1 << n);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++)
{
    std::vector<int> vi (n, 0);
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        vi[n - 1 - j] = (i & (1 << j)) ? (-1) : (+1);
    v.push_back(vi);
}
```

I'm sure someone can come up with a template meta-program that can construct `(v)` at compile-time for a constant `(n)`.